# how to find a subdocument as array and after inserting a new subdocument?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have searched for similar cases, but I was unable to find out where the problem is on the following code snippet.

My Schemas are like so:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var teamMemberModelSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    "email": {
        "type": String,
        "required": true,
        "min": 5,
        "max": 20
    },
    "name": {
        "type": String,
        "required": true,
        "min": 5,
        "max": 20
    },
    "role": {
        "type": String,
        "required": true,
        "min": 20,
        "max": 50
    },
    "twitter": {
        "type": String,
        "required": true,
        "min": 20,
        "max": 50
    },
    "facebook": {
        "type": String,
        "required": true,
        "min": 20,
        "max": 50
    },
    "linkedin": {
        "type": String,
        "required": true,
        "min": 20,
        "max": 50
    },
});

var teamModelSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    "title": {
        "type": String,
        "required": true,
        "min": 5,
        "max": 20
    },
    "headline": {
        "type": String,
        "required": true,
        "min": 5,
        "max": 30
    },
    "description": {
        "type": String,
        "required": true,
        "min": 5,
        "max": 80
    },
    "members": [teamMemberModelSchema]
}, { collection: 'team' });

teamModelSchema.set('collection', 'team');
mongoose.model('team', teamModelSchema);
mongoose.model('member', teamMemberModelSchema);
```

the problem comes at trying to add a new item to the members array inside the teamModelSchema.

It returns "TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"

```
module.exports.addTeamMember = function (req, res) {

    TeamModel.find().select("members").exec(
        function (err, teamInfo) {
            if (err) {
                responseUtilities.sendJsonResponse(res, err, teamInfo);
            } else {
                console.log(teamInfo);

                teamInfo.members.push({
                    email: req.body.email,
                    name: req.body.name,
                    role: req.body.role,
                    twitter: req.body.twitter,
                    facebook: req.body.facebook,
                    linkedin: req.body.linkedin
                });

                teamInfo.save(function (err, teamInfo) {
                    var thisMember;
                    if (err) {
                        responseUtilities.sendJsonResponse(res, err, teamInfo);
                    } else {
                        thisMember = teamInfo[teamInfo.length - 1];
                        responseUtilities.sendJsonResponse(res, err, teamInfo);
                    }
                });

            }
        }
    );

};
```

I have tried several variations, but no one with the desired result.

Given this scenario, how can I add a new item to members ?

PS: sendJsonResponse is only a function that does res status and json object.

Comment: can you share collection data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Lemix. After understading your help and some time trying, the solution that worked is as follows:

```
module.exports.addTeamMember = function (req, res) {

    TeamModel.find( TeamModel ).exec(
        function (err, teamInfo) {
            if (err) {
                responseUtilities.sendJsonResponse(res, err, teamInfo);
            } else {

                teamInfo[0].members.push({
                    email: req.body.email,
                    name: req.body.name,
                    role: req.body.role,
                    twitter: req.body.twitter,
                    facebook: req.body.facebook,
                    linkedin: req.body.linkedin
                });

                var membersLength = teamInfo[0].members.length - 1;
                var thisMember;
                thisMember = teamInfo[0].members[membersLength];

                var doc  = { id: teamInfo[0].description.id };
                var options = { $set: { id: teamInfo[0].id,
                                        description: teamInfo[0].description,
                                        headline: teamInfo[0].headline,
                                        title: teamInfo[0].title,
                                        members: teamInfo[0].members,
                                        }};

                 TeamModel.updateOne(doc, options,function (err, teamInfo) {
                    if (err) {
                        data = teamInfo;
                    }
                    else {
                        data = thisMember;
                    }
                    responseUtilities.sendJsonResponse(res, err, data);
                 }
                )};
            }
        );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `find()` returns array of documents
2. `teamInfo` variable is array
3. Array no contains `members` property

Use `findOne` to get a specific document or select a specific document from the array by index (e.g. `teamInfo[0].members.push`).

Comment: Hello, have a look at the solution that I found out. It worked. What do you think? is there any way to make it simplier?